# how to apply effects on selected image from gallery in android?

Tags: android

Actually I tried for "effects on image" that image was there in drawable folder by using Effectsfactory class. Its working fine.
Actually I used this link "http://grishma102.blogspot.in/2013/10/apply-effects-on-image-using-effects.html" for this code.
The code I used was..

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.media.effect.Effect;
import android.media.effect.EffectContext;
import android.media.effect.EffectFactory;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLUtils;
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    private GLSurfaceView mEffectView;
    private int[] mTextures = new int[2];
    private EffectContext mEffectContext;
    private Effect mEffect;
    private ThirdActivity mTexRenderer = new ThirdActivity();
    private int mImageWidth;
    private int mImageHeight;
    private boolean mInitialized = false;
    int mCurrentEffect;

    public void setCurrentEffect(int effect) {
        mCurrentEffect = effect;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        /**
         * Initialise the renderer and tell it to only render when
         * Explicit requested with the RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY option
         */
        mEffectView = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.effectsview);
        mEffectView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        mEffectView.setRenderer(this);
        mEffectView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
        mCurrentEffect = R.id.none;
    }

    private void loadTextures() {
        // Generate textures
        GLES20.glGenTextures(2, mTextures, 0);

        // Load input bitmap
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.puppy);
        mImageWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
        mImageHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
        mTexRenderer.updateTextureSize(mImageWidth, mImageHeight);

        // Upload to texture
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextures[0]);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

        // Set texture parameters
        SecondActivity.initTexParams();
    }

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi") @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) private void initEffect() {
        EffectFactory effectFactory = mEffectContext.getFactory();
        if (mEffect != null) {
            mEffect.release();
        }
        /**
         * Initialize the correct effect based on the selected menu/action item
         */
        switch (mCurrentEffect) {

            case R.id.none:
                break;

            case R.id.autofix:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_AUTOFIX);
                mEffect.setParameter("scale", 0.5f);
                break;

            case R.id.bw:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_BLACKWHITE);
                mEffect.setParameter("black", .1f);
                mEffect.setParameter("white", .7f);
                break;

            case R.id.brightness:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect (EffectFactory.EFFECT_BRIGHTNESS);
                mEffect.setParameter("brightness", 2.0f);
                break;

            case R.id.contrast:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_CONTRAST);
                mEffect.setParameter("contrast", 1.4f);
                break;

            case R.id.crossprocess:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_CROSSPROCESS);
                break;

            case R.id.documentary:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_DOCUMENTARY);
                break;

            case R.id.duotone:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_DUOTONE);
                mEffect.setParameter("first_color", Color.YELLOW);
                mEffect.setParameter("second_color", Color.DKGRAY);
                break;

            case R.id.filllight:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_FILLLIGHT);
                mEffect.setParameter("strength", .8f);
                break;

            case R.id.fisheye:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_FISHEYE);
                mEffect.setParameter("scale", .5f);
                break;

            case R.id.flipvert:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_FLIP);
                mEffect.setParameter("vertical", true);
                break;

            case R.id.fliphor:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_FLIP);
                mEffect.setParameter("horizontal", true);
                break;

            case R.id.grain:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_GRAIN);
                mEffect.setParameter("strength", 1.0f);
                break;

            case R.id.grayscale:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_GRAYSCALE);
                break;

            case R.id.lomoish:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_LOMOISH);
                break;

            case R.id.negative:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_NEGATIVE);
                break;

            case R.id.posterize:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_POSTERIZE);
                break;

            case R.id.rotate:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect( EffectFactory.EFFECT_ROTATE);
                mEffect.setParameter("angle", 180);
                break;

            case R.id.saturate:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_SATURATE);
                mEffect.setParameter("scale", .5f);
                break;

            case R.id.sepia:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_SEPIA);
                break;

            case R.id.sharpen:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_SHARPEN);
                break;

            case R.id.temperature:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_TEMPERATURE);
                mEffect.setParameter("scale", .9f);
                break;

            case R.id.tint:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_TINT);
                mEffect.setParameter("tint", Color.MAGENTA);
                break;

            case R.id.vignette:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_VIGNETTE);
                mEffect.setParameter("scale", .5f);
                break;

            default:
                break;

        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") private void applyEffect() {
        mEffect.apply(mTextures[0], mImageWidth, mImageHeight, mTextures[1]);
    }

    private void renderResult() {
        if (mCurrentEffect != R.id.none) {
            // if no effect is chosen, just render the original bitmap
            mTexRenderer.renderTexture(mTextures[1]);
        }
        else {
            // render the result of applyEffect()
            mTexRenderer.renderTexture(mTextures[0]);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        if (!mInitialized) {
            //Only need to do this once
            mEffectContext = EffectContext.createWithCurrentGlContext();
            mTexRenderer.init();
            loadTextures();
            mInitialized = true;
        }
        if (mCurrentEffect != R.id.none) {
            //if an effect is chosen initialize it and apply it to the texture
            initEffect();
            applyEffect();
        }
        renderResult();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        if (mTexRenderer != null) {
            mTexRenderer.updateViewSize(width, height);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        setCurrentEffect(item.getItemId());
        mEffectView.requestRender();
        return true;
    }

}
```

But I want to select image from gallery and for that image I want to apply effects. For that I used this code

```
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.effect.Effect;
import android.media.effect.EffectContext;
import android.media.effect.EffectFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLUtils;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

     private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

    private GLSurfaceView mEffectView;
    private int[] mTextures = new int[2];
    private EffectContext mEffectContext;
    private Effect mEffect;
    private ThirdActivity mTexRenderer = new ThirdActivity();
    private int mImageWidth;
    private int mImageHeight;
    private boolean mInitialized = false;
    int mCurrentEffect;
  // private Bitmap bitmap;

    public void setCurrentEffect(int effect) {
        mCurrentEffect = effect;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });


        /**
         * Initialise the renderer and tell it to only render when
         * Explicit requested with the RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY option
         */
        mEffectView = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.effectsview);
        mEffectView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        mEffectView.setRenderer(this);
        mEffectView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
        mCurrentEffect = R.id.none;
    }

    private void loadTextures() {
        // Generate textures
        GLES20.glGenTextures(2, mTextures, 0);

        // Load input bitmap
       // Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.puppy);
       Bitmap bitmap =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.id.imgView);


        mImageWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
        mImageHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
        mTexRenderer.updateTextureSize(mImageWidth, mImageHeight);

        // Upload to texture
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextures[0]);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

        // Set texture parameters
        SecondActivity.initTexParams();
        }

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi") @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) private void initEffect() {
        EffectFactory effectFactory = mEffectContext.getFactory();
        if (mEffect != null) {
            mEffect.release();
        }
        /**
         * Initialize the correct effect based on the selected menu/action item
         */
        switch (mCurrentEffect) {

            case R.id.none:
                break;

            case R.id.autofix:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_AUTOFIX);
                mEffect.setParameter("scale", 0.5f);
                break;

            case R.id.bw:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_BLACKWHITE);
                mEffect.setParameter("black", .1f);
                mEffect.setParameter("white", .7f);
                break;

            case R.id.brightness:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect (EffectFactory.EFFECT_BRIGHTNESS);
                mEffect.setParameter("brightness", 2.0f);
                break;

            case R.id.contrast:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_CONTRAST);
                mEffect.setParameter("contrast", 1.4f);
                break;

            case R.id.crossprocess:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_CROSSPROCESS);
                break;

            case R.id.documentary:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_DOCUMENTARY);
                break;

            case R.id.duotone:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_DUOTONE);
                mEffect.setParameter("first_color", Color.YELLOW);
                mEffect.setParameter("second_color", Color.DKGRAY);
                break;

            case R.id.filllight:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_FILLLIGHT);
                mEffect.setParameter("strength", .8f);
                break;

            case R.id.fisheye:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_FISHEYE);
                mEffect.setParameter("scale", .5f);
                break;

            case R.id.flipvert:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_FLIP);
                mEffect.setParameter("vertical", true);
                break;

            case R.id.fliphor:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_FLIP);
                mEffect.setParameter("horizontal", true);
                break;

            case R.id.grain:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_GRAIN);
                mEffect.setParameter("strength", 1.0f);
                break;

            case R.id.grayscale:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_GRAYSCALE);
                break;

            case R.id.lomoish:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_LOMOISH);
                break;

            case R.id.negative:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_NEGATIVE);
                break;

            case R.id.posterize:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_POSTERIZE);
                break;

            case R.id.rotate:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect( EffectFactory.EFFECT_ROTATE);
                mEffect.setParameter("angle", 180);
                break;

            case R.id.saturate:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_SATURATE);
                mEffect.setParameter("scale", .5f);
                break;

            case R.id.sepia:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_SEPIA);
                break;

            case R.id.sharpen:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_SHARPEN);
                break;

            case R.id.temperature:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_TEMPERATURE);
                mEffect.setParameter("scale", .9f);
                break;

            case R.id.tint:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_TINT);
                mEffect.setParameter("tint", Color.MAGENTA);
                break;

            case R.id.vignette:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_VIGNETTE);
                mEffect.setParameter("scale", .5f);
                break;

            default:
                break;

        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") private void applyEffect() {
        mEffect.apply(mTextures[0], mImageWidth, mImageHeight, mTextures[1]);
    }

    private void renderResult() {
        if (mCurrentEffect != R.id.none) {
            // if no effect is chosen, just render the original bitmap
            mTexRenderer.renderTexture(mTextures[1]);
        }
        else {
            // render the result of applyEffect()
            mTexRenderer.renderTexture(mTextures[0]);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        if (!mInitialized) {
            //Only need to do this once
            mEffectContext = EffectContext.createWithCurrentGlContext();
            mTexRenderer.init();
            loadTextures();
            mInitialized = true;
        }
        if (mCurrentEffect != R.id.none) {
            //if an effect is chosen initialize it and apply it to the texture
            initEffect();
            applyEffect();
        }
        renderResult();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        if (mTexRenderer != null) {
            mTexRenderer.updateViewSize(width, height);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        setCurrentEffect(item.getItemId());
        mEffectView.requestRender();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

            cursor.close();

                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        }

    }

}
```

But it was showing following error

01-27 15:21:19.010: E/AndroidRuntime(26361): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 2743
01-27 15:21:19.010: E/AndroidRuntime(26361): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-27 15:21:19.010: E/AndroidRuntime(26361):    at com.example.imageeffect.MainActivity.loadTextures(MainActivity.java:92)
01-27 15:21:19.010: E/AndroidRuntime(26361):    at com.example.imageeffect.MainActivity.onDrawFrame(MainActivity.java:270)
01-27 15:21:19.010: E/AndroidRuntime(26361):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1464)
01-27 15:21:19.010: E/AndroidRuntime(26361):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:121

please help me in solving this issue.

Comment: Bitmap bitmap =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.id.imgView); will be returning null, because R.id.imgView is a view id, not an image resource id

Answer (score 4):

I have the code that can apply the effect that selected from Gallery, you can refer to this one https://github.com/jtxyz0804/ImageFilter